# Dynamically enable/disable SUBMIT button in twig

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

Facing an issue that I could easily solve with the help of JS, but failing to do it in twig. I have a couple of fields in twig, and a submit button. I would want to validate these fields' data in frontend before actually submitting them, and have the "Submit" button disabled as long as the condition is unsatisfacatory. The problem in case:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group field">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea model="description" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    // checking if user has forgotten to add description, to prevent data submitting
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default blue" {% if description == "" } % disabled="disabled" {% endif %}>
    Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

In JS or AngularJSi could easily solve this problem, but is there any means of achieving the same result in Twig? I need it to check the status of description dynamically and react accordingly.

Already tried:

- min-length - does not prevent submitting, only colors the field after it is activated, does not work

Is there any means to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: add `}` after `{% if description == "" %`

Comment: Added, missed while asking the question.

Comment: have you try to test the description value with `dump` ?
May be try `{% if description is defined %}` instead `== ""`

Comment: `twig` is ran serverside. It cannot interact with user input before sending it back to the server. U only can use javascript (ajax) to do so

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I understand this. I was thinking about some sort of jQuery implementation that would be able to to it.

Comment: You're being unclear? Your question states "Is there any means of achieving the same result in Twig?" - So the answer is No

Comment: for dynamic behavior you need javascript